# Изменить стиль сайта через(из) расширения

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Есть ли какой нибудь простой способ изменить стиль определенного сайта, через расширение, при загрузке страницы?
(Например изменить `background` у `body`)

---

Можно пожалуйста код который будет в `manifest`, `options.html`, `options.js`?
И отдельно строчку кода где например меняется `background` у `body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел решение:

#### manifest:

```
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://vk.com/*"],
    "js": ["run.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  ...
}
```

#### run.js:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.body.style.background = "#2A2E3F"; 
}
```